# Django file not uploaded using FileField(upload to=)

Tags: python, django, file-upload, filefield

am very new to concepts of django and it's functionalities
so i came across a project which will easily help one to upload a file to a directory using FileField Upload to , but for me it is not working , i tried different ways i modifed it but still i am not sure about the error am getting .

So someone please guide me

here is my code :

**Models.py**

```
class UploadedFiles(models.Model):
    files_to_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploaded_files/', default=None, validators=[validate_file])
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    server = MultiSelectField(choices=server_list)

    SalesforceTicket = models.ForeignKey(SalesforceTicket, related_name="files", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.SalesforceTicket)
```

**forms.py**

```
class FilesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadedFiles
        fields = ['files_to_upload', 'path', 'server']

    # called on validation of the form
    def clean(self):
        # run the standard clean method first
        cleaned_data = super(FilesForm, self).clean()
        files_to_upload = cleaned_data.get("files_to_upload")
        path = cleaned_data.get("path")
        server = cleaned_data.get("server")
        # print(files_to_upload)
        # print(path)
        # print(server)
        new_path = path.replace(':', '$', 1)
        # print(new_path)
        mode = 0o666
        for s in server:
            s = r'\\' + s
            unc_path = os.path.join(s, new_path)
            print("hello"+unc_path)
            #unc_path = os.mkdir(unc_path, mode)
        isdir = os.path.isdir(unc_path)

        if isdir:
            print("ok")
        else:
            unc_path = os.mkdir(unc_path, mode)
        return cleaned_data
```

**Views.py**

```
def files(request):
    num_of_files = 1
    filled_multi_file_form = MultipleForm(request.GET)
    if filled_multi_file_form.is_valid():
        num_of_files = filled_multi_file_form.cleaned_data['num_of_files']

    FilesFormSet = formset_factory(FilesForm, extra=num_of_files)
    formset = FilesFormSet()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        filled_form = SnippetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       
        filled_formset = FilesFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if filled_form.is_valid() and filled_formset.is_valid():
                     print"hi"
```

in settings.py , i included MEDIA_ROOT = **'C:\newform-16oct**'

and in html :**enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"**

. Only thing that shows when i search on google is this , and my code is same as the one that is in google , don know whether am not able to identify error .

so after i migrate and run this , it is not throwing me any error , but when i check the folder it is empty

can anyone kindly help me

Error got after editing the code :
since the file is not copied to upload_files , when i try to copy the file to another network shared drive it is throwing me error , saying there is no file inside upload_files
[image: error]

so if i try to add using django admin [image: django admin] , it is thrwoing me below error

[image: error on django]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder will remain empty since you made a script that generates a new directory, but never do you ask to save that file there.

However I think you are solving the problem at the wrong location. The form does not need to handle that. A Django model can handle this: you can pass a function as value for the [**`upload_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```
class UploadedFiles(models.Model):
    def file_path(self, filename):
        return f'uploaded_files/{self.server}/{self.path.replace(":","$", 1)}/{filename}'
        
    files_to_upload = models.FileField(
        upload_to=file_path,
        default=None,
        validators=[validate_file]
    )
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    server = MultiSelectField(choices=server_list)

    SalesforceTicket = models.ForeignKey(
        SalesforceTicket,
        related_name='files',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.SalesforceTicket)
```

or something similar.

Comment: this works , but i don want whole folder , i just want to copy that file on to uploaded_files and not any other folder inside that , i have other function which fetch data directly from upload file . , so when i give return f'upload_file/' . it is not working ]

Comment: @AuroraEugene: then you use `f'upload_file/{filename}'`. But then of course constructing a new directory does not make much sense. You should simply let the function return the path where you want to store the data, and Django will automatically construct the directories. So there is no need to handle that logic in the form.

Comment: this was working first and not second time when i try to copy even though i deleted entire folders inside uploadfiles , and  i don want whole folder , i just want to copy that file on to uploaded_files and not any other folder inside that , i have other function which fetch data directly from upload file . , so when i give return f'upload_file/' . it is not working ] , and am getting an error like this , i will post the error in quesion

Comment: @AuroraEugene: but you need to specify `upload_file/{filename}` since otherwise you are uploading to an (already existing) directory, and you can not write data to a directory.

Comment: i did that already , but i am not getting it and i just want to keep the file uploaded to that uploaded_files folder

Comment: it was uploading at first , but not the second time . May i know why

Comment: @AuroraEugene: did you remove the logic of the `clean` method?

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: but the clean logic is the one which connects the path

Comment: @AuroraEugene: no, it is simply logic that makes a directory, where exactly do you say in that logic to store the file there? It is thus simply not necessary, and can potentially make a directory that prevents Django from writing to a file with the same name.

Comment: i will remove that and check now

Comment: sorry am getting the same error and no file is getting uploaded into upload_files

Comment: @AuroraEugene: for existing records that will of course not fix anything. Clean the database...

Comment: i didn't use any db in here , will it be the reason . i am not saving data to django admin. since i have my own log . And am not really sure why this files are not moving to uploaded_files folder

Comment: @AuroraEugene: well then there is not much need to use models either, since a model is all about storing data in the database. But this is basically the core feature of Django...

Comment: oh , so my django admin contains two table now with diff column , so when i try now , it is throwing me error like no tablename found . or could not add to this . Is there any way to delete existing  ones created and create new one

Comment: i tried using unregister, but was not working

Comment: i will attach my django admin in question , and the error am getting when i try to add data using django admin

Comment: @AuroraEugene: you should `makemigrations` and `migrate`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations .

Comment: i made migrations , but it was adding an additional s at the end of table created , can u just check the screensht