# Django Admin not allowing to enter data to table

Tags: python, django, file-upload, filefield

So am using django admin in my project , i already had some columns during development of my project , as time went the column is reduced from 2 to 1 and column name is changed . So i made changes in code but i am not able to write to django admin . inn django admin UI or in django code . it says table not present

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import SalesforceTicket, UploadedFiles

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(SalesforceTicket)
admin.site.register(UploadedFiles)
```

**views.py**

```
def files(request):
    num_of_files = 1
    filled_multi_file_form = MultipleForm(request.GET)
    if filled_multi_file_form.is_valid():
        num_of_files = filled_multi_file_form.cleaned_data['num_of_files']

    FilesFormSet = formset_factory(FilesForm, extra=num_of_files)
    formset = FilesFormSet()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        filled_form = SnippetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        filled_formset = FilesFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if filled_form.is_valid() and filled_formset.is_valid():
            
            SalesforceTicket = filled_form.save(commit=False)
            SalesforceTicket.save()
           
            SalesforceNumber = filled_form.cleaned_data['SalesforceNumber']
           

            for form in filled_formset:
                data = form.save(commit=False)
                data.SalesforceTicket = SalesforceTicket
                data.save()
                file = form.cleaned_data['files_to_upload']
                path = form.cleaned_data['path']
                server = form.cleaned_data['server']
                         
                note = 'File Uploaded Successfully !!'
                filled_form = SnippetForm()
                filled_formset = FilesFormSet()

        else:
            note = 'Please try again!'


        return render(request, 'myforms/files.html',
                      {'note': note, 'SnippetForm': filled_form, 'formset': filled_formset})
    else:
        form1 = SnippetForm()
        filled_formset = FilesFormSet()
        return render(request, 'myforms/files.html', {'SnippetForm': form1, 'formset': filled_formset})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import SalesforceTicket, UploadedFiles
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
import os, pathlib
import logging


class SnippetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SalesforceTicket
        fields = ['SalesforceNumber']


class FilesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadedFiles
        fields = ['files_to_upload', 'path', 'server']
    def clean(self): 
        cleaned_data = super(FilesForm, self).clean()
        #files_to_upload = cleaned_data.get("files_to_upload")
        path = cleaned_data.get("path")
        server = cleaned_data.get("server")
        new_path = path.replace(':', '$', 1)
        # print(new_path)
        mode = 0o666
        for s in server:
            s = r'\\' + s
            unc_path = os.path.join(s, new_path)
            print("hello"+unc_path)
            #unc_path = os.mkdir(unc_path, mode)
        isdir = os.path.isdir(unc_path)

        if isdir:
            print("ok")
        else:
            unc_path = os.mkdir(unc_path, mode)
        return cleaned_data


class MultipleForm(forms.Form):
    num_of_files = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=10)
```

and i was getting error while uploading to file , actually it was not upload : Question was already posted on Stack , don know whether django admin is the problem for that cause .

and so i tried inserting data using django admin UI :

[image: django admin]

so am getting this error :'=
[image: eror]

link to my previous question:[Django file not uploaded using FileField(upload to=)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66255218/15219573)

so i applied makemigration followed my migrate and runserver and tried adding into django salesforce model table .

so here is the migration log produced :
[image: migration log]

and here is the error am getting when i try to add the data to db table [image: after trying to add content to db table];

So do anyone know the reason

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when you have not made migrations after the newly created table- in your case table is `SalesforceTicket`

First make migrations as: `python manage.py makemigrations` and then apply those migrations using this command : `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: May i know something is the one displayed in django UI is table name , should that one and the one in code be same , or is there any other table name , since when i give uploadfile as model name , in django admin UI it is displayed as  uploadfiles

Comment: @AuroraEugene try `python manage.py makemigrations <appname>` does that generate any migrations? Note: replace `<appname>` with the name of your app.

Comment: migration is fdone , it changed my table name in Django admin, but i don know why that error still comes , it says table salesforceticket not found , and one more thing is an additional 's'  is added to the instance during migration

Comment: so after make migration when i check the log in migration it shows the table name as salesforce ticket , but when i run django admin it says there is no table names salesforceticket